# CKEditor5 in React not working with a nonce in Content-Security-Policy

Tags: reactjs, webpack, content-security-policy, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor in a React application using `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react: 5.1.0` and     `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic: ^40.1.0`.  We use Webpack 5.

My Content-Security-Policy contains `strict-dynamic` and a nonce and not `unsafe-inline`.

I have stepped through the WebPack loader code and found that it is correctly passing the nonce when loading the bundle containing CKEditor.

However, Chrome is reporting 78 errors like this:

ckeditor.js:6 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' `https://localhost:10111/` 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-fakeNonce';" Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-d6j8IAY0zOxGlurXvxqXGX9jHRbyhvJvE6CdKjQIic4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

How can I best resolve this?  I didn't find anything in the doc about passing a nonce via CKEditor config.  Using hashes seems impractical as there are so many.
,

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to have nothing really to do with ckeditor but actually with the webpack style-loader plugin that was used to build the classic editor.  The bug is long open but has a workaround.  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/427

Even after applying the workaround, there were still some issues.  The answer turned out to be using `mini-css-extract-plugin` instead of the `style-loader` in a ckeditor custom build.  This is documented near the end of this file https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/alternative-setups/integrating-from-source-webpack.html